# Make {{!LOOP}} increase by 10 in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I have problems with making !LOOP jump +10 each time instead of +1.

Here is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !VAR1 100
SET !LOOP {{!VAR1}}

URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/lui/?page={{!LOOP}}

WAIT SECONDS=1

ADD !VAR1 10
```

Running this still makes iMacros jump +1 each loop.

Above sample goes to page=100,page=101,page=102,page=103 **instead of** page=100,page=110,page=120

Best regards,

Lui Kang

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The variable {{!LOOP}} represents the current loop number when a script is running in loop mode.

You can still get `100`,`110`,`120`... via a javascript expression: `init+step*loop`.

Try the [`EVAL`](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL) command:

```
SET !LOOP 0
SET INIT 100
SET STEP 10
SET VALUE EVAL("{{INIT}}+{{STEP}}*{{!LOOP}}")
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/lui/?page={{VALUE}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/lui/?page={{number}}"+"\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=1"+"\n";

//declare the number
var number=10;


//loop 
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{

//set the number to macro
iimSet("number",number)
iimPlay(macro)

//increase by 10
number =number+10;

}
```

I prefer the JavaScript solution(s). Place this into .js file (and only .js file) and play it in iMacros. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I need to make macros for a site , which has variable wait time , so how can i get the wait time from the page and add it to the script as a variable

the value of VAR2 is shown on the page URL , I need to assign that value to VAR2

WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR2}}

Here is the HTML Code Of the Page :

```
<font color="maroon" size="2"><b>Timer</b>: <span id="count1820380num">50</span>/133</font>
```

The Value 133 should me made as waiting time !